# IllegalArgumentException when trying to update an object with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, illegalargumentexception

Using Parse.com, I want to retrieve an object from the local DB, update a field and save it back to the Parse Cloud... here is my code so far:

```
String objId = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_OBJ_ID");

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("someTable");
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.getInBackground(objId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Date expiry = parseObject.getDate("expiryDate");
            long millis = expiry.getTime();
            Date current = new Date();
            parseObject.add("expiryDate", current);
            parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        //success
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

but at `parseObject.add("expiryDate", current);` I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Operation is invalid after previous operation.
        at com.parse.ParseAddOperation.apply(ParseAddOperation.java:71)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.performOperation(ParseObject.java:2725)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.addAll(ParseObject.java:2813)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.add(ParseObject.java:2799)
        at com.app.ConversationActivity$8.done(ConversationActivity.java:297)
        at com.app.ConversationActivity$8.done(ConversationActivity.java:283)
        at com.parse.Parse$5$1.run(Parse.java:924)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is almost copy-pasted from Parse docs, except that I'm querying from local datastore... so how can I make this work?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Do not do the following:
    parseObject.add("expiryDate", current);

**instead, do this:**
    parseObject.put("expiryDate", current);

From Parse's documentation

> add(String key, Object value)Atomically adds an object to the end of the array associated with a given key.

"expiryDate" is not an array it is a Date field for your ParseObject in "someTable". So you just want to update it's value via a call to put, rather than add.

The put operation is what you are looking for, and should work.

Side Note:
You may want to use [saveEventually()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveEventually(com.parse.SaveCallback)) in order to save to the cloud, and also to the local datastore as well. Since it seems you are trying to take your Parse application offline as well.